# Electrostatic potential of a point charge

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential_energy)

> The electrostatic potential energy, UE, of one point charge q at position r in the presence of an electric field E is defined as the negative of the work W done by the electrostatic force to bring it from the reference position rref[note 1] to that position r.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIL4l.png)[2]:§25-1[note 2]

[image]

Since the potential energy is defined as negative of work done by the conservative force. I will proceed with the proof by calculation work done by the force in bringing the point charge q from $\infty$ to $r$.

I have used $dx$ instead of $ds$ as depicted in the diagram.

$$W=F_{Qq}\cdot dx$$
Since the direction of the force by Q on q ($F_{Qq}$) is antiparallel the dot product is resolved as
$$W=F_{Qq}\times dx \cos(180^{\circ})$$
$$W=-F_{Qq}\times dx$$

Now, subbing in the value of $F_{Qq}= \frac{k Qq}{x^2}$

$$W=-\int_{\infty}^{r} \frac{k Qq}{x^2}dx$$
$$W=\bigg[\frac{kQq}{x}\bigg]_{\infty}^{r}$$
$$W=\frac{kQq}{r}$$

Since this is the work calculated therefore potential energy is its negative:

$$U=-\frac{kQq}{r}$$

However the correct expression for the potential energy of two point charges is

$$U=\frac{kQq}{r}$$

I can't find anything wrong with my proof but it **is** wrong, why?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/436432/104696) which explains that the direction of $d\vec x$ is entirely determined by the path taken or the limits of integration.

Answer (score 1):

You should work with $d\vec{r}$ instead of $d\vec{x}$. As they are opposite, that's your problem.